# Replacing activity in activity stack

Tags: android, android-activity

I read docs about activity stack and searching for an answer on forums but I can't find a solution for my problem.
I have activity A (which is a ImageView) and activity B (is a GridView). When user clicks on some picture in GridView activity A opens with corresponding Image.

So I have such situation in activity stack after choosing another picture in GridView:
 ... -> A(picture 1) -> B(grid) -> A(picture 2)

But I want to have: ... -> B(grid) - A(picture 2)

I tried different launch modes:
if A is a singleInstance - after choosing any picture in grid, activity A opens with old image
if A is a singleTask - i get situation: A(picture 1) -> B(grid) -> A(picture 2)

Can anybody give me a point how manage my activities the way I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the onPause() of Activity A and call finish();

Therefore when 'back' is pressed on the ImageView it will remove it from the stack.

Then your stack will only ever be: Grid -> Image

Also if your activity is sent to the background (with home button) your stack will be: Grid

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It really works for me. But is there a way to fix this without overriding onPause(onStop, etc.)?

Comment: It's correct to override onPause() :-) that is what they are there for.  Scroll down to the lifecycle here for whats possible: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html Please mark the question as answered if this fixed it. (On the left of the answer under the 0 press the green tick) This helps others.

Comment: There is problem with onPause() - the activity will be finished after leaving activity A) But I need activity A be finished ONLY when I start A with new info. Till then I need A in activity stack. Do you know solution for this problem?
I will be so grateful.

Comment: Yes you simply set a boolean flag, and do: if(myFlag) finish(); You can send the flag from the last activity using the Intent extra's

Comment: Man, you are my hero! ) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to finish your Activity A when you go back to B. I assume you are not using the standard back mechanism, and opening another Activity B hence your problem.